# How to use argv as variable

Tags: c++, string, argv

I would like to use a given Variable for my Main-function in c++ to be used as part of the name of the outputfile. The code is:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
fstream f,g;
string s1,s2,name;
name = argv[5];

s1 = name+("_systemvalues.dat");
f.open(s1.c_str(), ios::out);
...
c.close();
```

An, for example, argv[5] should be "test". The program is compiling and it is running as well, but the output file is not produced. 
I can display s1 on the terminal and it is what it should be - but the outputfile is simply not produced.

Comment: What is `c.close()` should be `f.close()` ? Do you mind showing entire code ?

Comment: There is no file, or the file is empty?

Comment: If `s1` is what you want, the problem is probably not `argv`. You should be closing the file with `f.close()`, and show us how you are writing to it.

Comment: Use `f.isopen()` and `f.good()` to see if the file stream has been created correctly.

Comment: Technically, if `f.open()` succeeds, the file should be there [assuming of course also that there isn't any "delete the file" operations later on.

Comment: maybe try f.is_open() to make sure the file have actually been opened

Comment: Hi, it is f.close(). And the entire code is by far too long to show it here. Also, there is no file, it is not only empty.

Comment: Writing in the file is not the problem, when I, for example, write name=("test") it is working fine.

Comment: isopen isn't working (function doesn't exist), good() gives false

Comment: is_open() gives also false

Comment: "write name="test" it is working fine" -- How can you know that? Did you add error checking to the relevant routines? As a test, do not create your new file with a variable name but with a full fixed path and filename. It might be it just gets created in an unexpected folder -- a known issue in some IDEs.

Comment: I can know it because I can simply replace the variable by "test"

Comment: If I change the `c.close()` to `f.close()`, then the code works fine on my machine and creates the file. It's probably a problem with write permissions or that the file is created in another directory. Check in the `~/` path.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you don't have the required `write` permissions to make changes to the filesystem / directory.

```
chmod -R 777 mydir
```

By the way you could use std::ofstream for the job. It will create the file for you if it doesn't already exist.

```
   #include <string>
   #include <iostream>
   #include <fstream>  

   /* ... */

   std::string name = "";
   name.append(argv[5]);
   name.append("_systemvalues.dat");

   std::ofstream out(name.c_str());

   out << "text" << std::endl;

   out.close();

   /* ... */
```

Comment: Sorry - doesn't work. There is still no file produced. And I guess you mean argv[0] instead of argc[0]

Comment: @user1978661 Did you check the permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Ok... the problem was the input. The character '/' cannnot be used as part of a filename - with hindsight it is really clear.